# Hive Insert overwrite into Dynamic partition external table from a raw external table failed with null pointer exception.,

Tags: hadoop, nullpointerexception, mapreduce, hive, external-tables

I have a raw external table with four columns-
Table 1 :

> create external table external_partitioned_rawtable
>  (age_bucket
>   String,country_destination String,gender
>   string,population_in_thousandsyear int)
>  row format delimited
>   fields terminated by '\t' 
>  lines terminated by '\n' location
>   '/user/HadoopUser/hive'

I want a external table with partitions from Country_destination and gender.Table -2

> create external table external_partitioned 
>  (age_bucket
>   String,population_in_thousandsyear int) 
>  partitioned
>   by(country_destination String,gender String) 
>  row format delimited
>   fields terminated by '\t'  
>  lines terminated by '\n';

Insert Overwrite is failing with null pointer exception-

```
insert overwrite  table  external_partitioned partition(country_destination,gender) <br>
select (age_bucket,population_in_thousandsyear,country_destination,gender) <br>
from external_partitioned_rawtable;
```

**FAILED: NullPointerException null**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For dynamic partition insertion, before executing the `INSERT` statement you have to execute two properties of hive:

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
```

then execute insert statement(which I have modified)

```
insert overwrite  table  external_partitioned partition(country_destination,gender) 
select age_bucket,population_in_thousandsyear,country_destination,gender 
from external_partitioned_rawtable;
```

I hope this help you!!!

Comment: Thanks a lot it helped,Why should we use non strict mode?

Comment: By default it is set to strict mode. In strict mode dynamic partition is not allowed. Thatwhy you have to set nonstrict